# Magnetic hysteresis BH curve to compare “Fe-Ni” and “Si-Fe”

Tags: magnetic-fields, material-science

I am compiling some training material and would like to include a graph to indicate the different characteristics of silicon steel "Si-Fe" and mu-metal "Fe-Ni". The best curve I could find in SI units below seems theoretical.

Does anyone have a better graph or real data that can be used?  I can then use pgfplots to create the curves.

[image]

(this is a cross post from Electrical Engineering)

Comment: What is wrong with these curves? What kind of curve would be "better"? Also, could you tell us why you need this curve? Context always helps to write a good answer. Finally, please consider removing one of the cross posts. Our general rules apply also to questions with bounties. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/497147/magnetic-hysteresis-bh-curve-to-compare-fe-ni-fe-si

Comment: This is for training material.  It is visible that the curve has been approximated.  I would like the similar curves plotted indicating the difference in saturation and losses at saturation with actual data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this Figure? It is part of a publication by A Krings and J Soulard. If you access the figure via the publication, it also has axis labels and SI unit scales: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7194514

[image]

Comment: Nice, but I think they might have normalised the y-axis.  1.2 T for NiFe?

Comment: They report a max of 1.2 T for NiFe in the paper. I'm afraid I can't comment much more than that - it's not really my area of expertise.

Comment: I have sent an email to the authors.  They might clarify the issue.

Comment: They confirmed it is a high content NiFe.